# What is the data dictionary in NLP?

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am new to NLP and its concepts. I am currently trying to use [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/) from Apache. When I try to use its parser tool as shown in [blog](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/05/opennlp-tutorial/), I get the output like:

```
Input: Shutdown all active devices

Output: 
(TOP(VP(VB Shutdown)
(NP(DT all)
    (JJ active)
    (NNS devices))))
```

I am unable to understand what is the meaning of all the acronyms. Some of them I could understand from [Stanford's OpenNLP implementation](https://stanbol.apache.org/) of the same. But not all.

Can anyone point me to some proper direction as to how can I understand it and better, as to how can my code understand what is being said.

Comment: The URL behind the link "Stanford's OpenNLP..." seems to be misplaced? It points to Apache Stanbol, a project "intended use is to extend traditional content management systems with semantic services." Sure, this is what your meant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, learning like in any subject takes time so don't rush it or you will confuse yourself. The output syntax you see is a tree which take on the form of a series of lists and embedded lists. It may remind you of the syntax of a popular LISP such as [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)) or [Clojure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure).

```
(TOP(VP(VB Shutdown)
(NP(DT all)
    (JJ active)
    (NNS devices))))
```

The tags to the left of the words / lists are what is known as POS ([Part-of-Speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging)) Tags, that represent the grammatical category the word falls into, essentially a word-category disambiguation. POS tagging is still one of the very difficult research areas of Natural Language Processing as a subject with F1-Scores in their high 90%'s. Your tree snippet built out (with the list below) looks as follows:

```
(TOP(Verb, non-3rd-person(Verb Shutdown)
(Noun-Phrase (Determiner all)
    (Adjective active)
    (Noun-plural devices))))
```

POS Tagging is a great linguistic feature for tasks such as semantic parsing or named entity recognition. Some good resources to learn from include:

1. [NLTK (Natural Language Toolkit) Book Chapter 5](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html)
2. [Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Foundations-Statistical-Natural-Language-Processing/dp/0262133601/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1443426144&sr=8-1&keywords=foundations%20of%20statistical%20natural%20language%20processing)
3. [Part of Speech Tagging and Partial Parsing](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-1183-8_4)

**List of Part-of-Speech Tags (Penn Treebank corpus)**

3. **CC** ~ Coordinating conjunction
4. **CD** ~ Cardinal number
5. **DT** ~ Determiner
6. **EX** ~ Existential there
7. **FW** ~ Foreign word
8. **IN** ~ Preposition or subordinating conjunction
9. **JJ** ~ Adjective
10. **JJR** ~ Adjective, comparative
11. **JJS** ~ Adjective, superlative
12. **LS** ~ List item marker
13. **MD** ~ Modal
14. **NN** ~ Noun, singular or mass
15. **NNS** ~ Noun, plural
16. **NNP** ~ Proper noun, singular
17. **NNPS** ~ Proper noun, plural
18. **PDT** ~ Predeterminer
19. **POS** ~ Possessive ending
20. **PRP** ~ Personal pronoun
21. **PRP$** ~ Possessive pronoun
22. **RB** ~ Adverb
23. **RBR** ~ Adverb, comparative
24. **RBS** ~ Adverb, superlative
25. **RP** ~ Particle
26. **SYM** ~ Symbol
27. **TO** ~ to
28. **UH** ~ Interjection
29. **VB** ~ Verb, base form
30. **VBD** ~ Verb, past tense
31. **VBG** ~ Verb, gerund or present participle
32. **VBN** ~ Verb, past participle
33. **VBP** ~ Verb, non-3rd person singular present
34. **VBZ** ~ Verb, 3rd person singular present
35. **WDT** ~ Wh-determiner
36. **WP** ~ Wh-pronoun
37. **WP$** ~ Possessive wh-pronoun
38. **WRB** ~ Wh-adverb

Comment: Yeah, of course. I will update my answer. Are you comfortable reading through academic journals or should I avoid these?

Comment: anything is good...i am a software dev...was working on something that is supposed to understand command sentences just like SIRI or Cortana
So needed some quick ref and some in-depth knowldge...:)

Comment: Updated for some quick resources. In that case I recommend you look into semantic parsing.

Comment: You're welcome. If it helps please consider accepting my answer :-)